# ASP.NET - Asynchronously load UpdatePanels when page loads

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, updatepanel

I have a page which uses [WebParts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0s9t4ck.aspx) to display differents sections that the users can configurate, so in this page can be lots of them, each of them calling to our API to retrieve DB data.

Right now, these sections are loading synchronously, and the page may need too much time to load, so I've wrapped each section in an UpdatePanel and tried to load them asynchronously. I use an `asp:Timer` to do so. Now, the page renders and then the UpdatePanels start to load when the timer ticks, but the problem is that these UpdatePanels load synchronously (one after the other). So, if the first UpdatePanel needs 10 seconds to load, the second one will start to load just after.

What can I do to load them all at once asynchronously?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

asp.net webforms is not designed to work asynchronously, so as far as i know you cannot tweaks the updatepanels to do that.
I suppose you could somehow overload the updatepanel scripts, but it would really add too much complexity.

The easiest thing you could do is to not load all the webparts in the same page.